# Saving document the first time with MongoTemplate

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, mongodb-query, spring-data-mongodb

I'm facing a problem saving a document at the first time with MongoTemplate.
I have many records come to the server concurrently , these records have the same identity , so I save first arrived record in mongo and all the other records will update the saved document.

Example :

```
record1(id=x) , record2(id=x),record3(id=x),record4(id=x),record5(id=x),record6(id=x),.....
```

I need to save only `record1(id=x)` , and all the others to update the document.

Because of the concurrency , many records saved at the first time .
Is there a built in solution to this problem before going to other logic work around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic solution is called an ["upsert"](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#upsert-option). It is a built in function on a MongoDB [`.update()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/) method and carried through all drivers.

Just like any invocation of the `.update()` method, this requires two basic parameters consisting of a "query" object and and "update" object. The "update" object uses [operators](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/) to define the behavior of an update. There is a third option in the general command form that allow the option to ["upsert"](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#upsert-option) to be set.

Consider the following statements in the shell:

```
db.collection.update({ "_id": 1 },{ "$inc": { "counter": 1 } },{ "upsert" true })
db.collection.update({ "_id": 1 },{ "$inc": { "counter": 2 } },{ "upsert" true })
db.collection.update({ "_id": 1 },{ "$inc": { "counter": 3 } },{ "upsert" true })
```

Which will on the first statement create a new document with a "counter" value of `1`. The subsequent statements will increment in `2` and `3` respectively. No matter what the order of the statement execution, there is only one document at the end with a "counter" value of `6`.

In Spring data MongoDB, the mongoOperations class instance has a method called [`.upsert()`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/MongoOperations.html#upsert-org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Query-org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Update-java.lang.Class-) which does the same basic thing.

```
mongoOperations.upsert(query,update,Class.class)
```

Answer (score 0):

For the specific question you asked (just saving an object) you should use MongoTemplate's **save()** method. See [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/MongoOperations.html#save-java.lang.Object-) for the documentation.

You also asked about concurrency in your example, MongoDB guarantees atomicity per document. But you should be aware that *cross document atomicity* is not provided in MongoDB

Comment: For the record, `.save()` is really a base driver feature implemented in most language drivers and taken on by various higher level extensions ( such as SpringData MongoDB ) to be consistent with common API. It is a "very limited" form of "upsert", in that none of the "update operators" such as `$inc` or `$set` or `$push` etc are supported. It just replaces an object in entirety. Which is something that optimal code should almost never do.